# Is there a modbus implementation which uses Mina 2.x?

Tags: java, networking, apache-mina, modbus

Is there a open source modbus implementation **which uses Apache Mina 2.x**?

Answer (score 1):

Something from http://freemodbus.berlios.de/ can be certainly used.

For C# http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/modbuscs.aspx

Comment: I know that there are modbus implementations out there, my question was if specifically one **which utilizes apache mina** - is available!